# React warns about passed prop with value null, where the PropType for the prop is not required

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that receives *error* as either a string or an object with 2 required properties. But **null** can also be passed for this prop. In my current setup React throws a warning when **null** is passed:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `error` supplied to
>   `ErrorDialog`

What shall I change for React to allow **null | string | object with this shape**? Thank you!

```js
ErrorDialog.propTypes = {
  onResetError: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  error: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      defaultMessage: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
    PropTypes.string,
  ]),
};
```

The full code is:

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';

const ErrorDialog = ({ error, onResetError }) => {
  function renderError() {
    if (!error) {
      return null;
    } else if (typeof error === 'string') {
      return error;
    } else if (typeof error === 'object') {
      return <FormattedMessage {...error} />;
    }
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Dialog
      modal={false}
      open={Boolean(error)}
      actions={
        <FlatButton
          label="OK"
          primary
          onTouchTap={onResetError}
        />
      }
    >
      {renderError()}
    </Dialog>
  );
};

ErrorDialog.propTypes = {
  onResetError: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  error: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      defaultMessage: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }),
    PropTypes.string,
  ]),
};

export default ErrorDialog;
```

I want to hide the dialog, when there is no error, show original string, if the error is of type string and render a translated message if a message descriptor is specified.

UPDATE: I went with the solution like this:

```js
ErrorDialog.propTypes = {
  onResetError: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
  error(props, propName, componentName) {
    const prop = props[propName];
    if (prop !== null &&
        typeof prop !== 'string' &&
        !(typeof prop === 'object' && prop.id && prop.defaultMessage)) {
      return new Error(
        `Invalid prop \`${propName}\` supplied to ${componentName}. Validation failed.`
      );
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: can you share your code, so that we can check?

Comment: @Md.EstiakAhmmed added the full code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/1668) and [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3163) for discussions happened in the past. Just make `props.error` optional and check the value in your code. Otherwise, you would need to implement your own custom [prop validation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation).

From the docs:

```
// You can also specify a custom validator. It should return an Error
// object if the validation fails. Don't `console.warn` or throw, as this
// won't work inside `oneOfType`.
customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
  if (!/matchme/.test(props[propName])) {
    return new Error(
      'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
      ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
    );
  }
}
```